# Accordion menu, when i recreate an item several times, i change the id but the functionality still opens up all items

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a simple horizontal menu on the left hand side of my page. I'm trying to add more items to the menu; specifically items that have sub-menu's. The original menu looks like this:

```
<nav class="mainMenu">
                    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-42"><a href="about/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">About Us</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-733" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-733"><a href="about/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">About Us</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-443" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-443"><a href="about/service/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">Service</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-444" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-444"><a href="about/the-team/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">The Team</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-441" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-441"><a href="about/careers/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">Careers</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-442" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-442"><a href="about/ethos/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">Ethos</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-39" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-39"><a href="portfolio/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">Portfolio</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-project-category menu-item-56"><a href="project-category/architecture/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">Architecture</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-project-category menu-item-57"><a href="project-category/interiors/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">Interiors</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-project-category menu-item-58"><a href="project-category/landscapes/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">Landscapes</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-40"><a href="news/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">News</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-54"><a href="category/planning/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">Planning</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-53"><a href="category/on-site/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">On-Site</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-52"><a href="category/office/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">Office</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-51"><a href="category/in-design/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">In Design</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-55"><a href="category/publications/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">Publications</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-50"><a href="category/responsibility/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">Corporate Responsibility</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41"><a href="contact/index.html"><i class="icon-menu-icon"></i><span class="text">Contact</span></a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

When I try to recreate a menu item with a child/sub-menu it appears fine but than the functionality is a bit bonkers. Let's say i try to duplicate the "news" menu item. I'll recreate it right below news and i'll change the id's from 40 to 43 on the duplicated menu item "news".

The problem is when i click on the new item both the original and the new item subsidiary menus open.

I thought it was as simple as just creating new id's but i guess i failed on my understanding of how this works. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

CSS:

```
/*****************************************/
/*               Sidebar                 */
/*****************************************/
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: -15.625em;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 15.625em;
  padding-top: 2.5em;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "freight-sans-pro", serif;
  background: #1c1f20;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Open State */
  /* Main Menu */
  /* Footer Details (at bottome) */
}
.pushed .sidebar {
  left: 0;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li {
  padding: 1.125em 1em 0.875em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #252829;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > a > i {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  color: #a4a4a4;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > a:after {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #a4a4a4;
  font-family: 'iconsStudioIndigo';
  content: '\e624';
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > a:only-child:after {
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul {
  margin-left: 3.3em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  margin: 0.35em 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #a4a4a4;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li > a:focus, .sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: white;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li > a i {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 2px 7px 0 0;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.125s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.125s;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.25s;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.375s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.375s;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.5s;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.625s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.625s;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.75s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.75s;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.875s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.875s;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 1s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 1s;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 1.125s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 1.125s;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 1.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 1.25s;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li > ul > li.current-menu-item a i {
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li.current-menu-parent > a:after, .sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li.current-menu-item > a:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li.current-menu-parent > ul, .sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li.current-menu-item > ul {
  max-height: 10.625em;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li.current-menu-parent > ul > li, .sidebar .mainMenu > ul > li.current-menu-item > ul > li {
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar .mainMenu .menu-item i:before {
  content: '\e624';
}
.sidebar .mainMenu .menu-item-42 i:before {
  content: '\e623';
}
.sidebar .mainMenu .menu-item-39 i:before {
  content: '\e611';
}
.sidebar .mainMenu .menu-item-40 i:before {
  content: '\e61e';
}
.sidebar .mainMenu .menu-item-41 i:before {
  content: '\e620';
}
.sidebar .mainMenu .sub-menu .menu-item i:before {
  content: '\e607';
}
.sidebar .footerDetails {
  margin: 1.92308em 1.15385em;
  font-size: 0.8125em;
  color: #a4a4a4;
}
.sidebar .footerDetails li {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-top: 0.9375rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sidebar .footerDetails li a {
  color: #a4a4a4;
}
.sidebar .footerDetails li a:focus, .sidebar .footerDetails li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
.sidebar .footerDetails .copyright li,
.sidebar .footerDetails .textPages li,
.sidebar .footerDetails .credit li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-top: 0.625rem;
  text-transform: none;
}
.sidebar .footerDetails .textPages {
  margin-top: 1.53846em;
}
.sidebar .footerDetails .credit {
  margin-top: 1.15385em;
}
.sidebar .footerDetails .credit a {
  color: #737575;
}
.sidebar .footerDetails .credit a:hover {
  color: #76c044;
}
@media screen and (min-height: 45em) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 6.25em;
  }
  .sidebar .footerDetails {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    left: 0.9375rem;
    bottom: 25px;
    bottom: 1.5625rem;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .sidebar .footerDetails .textPages {
    margin-top: 2.69231em;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .sidebar {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: post your css so we can help you.

Comment: Okay, yeah.. oopps sorry about that.

Comment: updated @Alek.. thank for the reminder.. completely spaced on that.

Comment: Just some friendly advice: to improve the quality of your question (and the likelihood of it being answered quickly) reduce your html and css to ONLY the code relevant to your question. You make us do a lot of footwork for you. Cheers!

Comment: Understandable, noted! Thank you @philtune.

Comment: You should use jquery. It will minimize the code by a lot. $.click(function(){  /* addClass | removeClass */ }

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and it doesn't function at all as a menu. I'm assuming you have some Javascript that's managing the functionality. Otherwise, when I click a menu item it just acts like a link.

Here are some basics of CSS/Javascript menus that might be helpful:

### The HTML

Say you have the following unordered list:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li class="dropdown"><span class="togglable">Products</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Oranges</li>
            <li>Apples</li>
            <li>Bananas</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><span class="togglable">Blog</span>
        <ul>
            <li>My first post</li>
            <li>My last post</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS Hover Menus

You just want to show the first level of the menu at first so:

```
.menu .dropdown>ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999em;
}
```

Then you want to display it anytime the menu item is hovered:

```
.menu .dropdown:hover>ul {
    position:static;
    left:auto;
}
```

That's it. You can change it up a bit on how you want to hide/show your "submenus", like `display:none;` to `display:block;`, or `opacity:0;` to `opacity:1;` (which is my favorite because you can animate the opacity), but it's basically the same idea with the selectors. You can duplicate the menu to your heart's content.

Heck, you don't necessarily even need the `.dropdown` class, as you could just target any list items with `<ul>` descendants:

```
ul.menu>li>ul { display:none; }
ul.menu>li:hover>ul { display:block; }
```

### Javascript/CSS Hybrid (aka "Togglers")

I like to use minimal Javascript and let CSS do most of the magic. Here's some jQuery (if anyone can whip up the VanillaJS, feel free to edit this):

```
$('.menu .togglable')click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
    return false; //just so the browser doesn't follow the link if it's an anchor
}
```

This will turn on/off a `.toggled` class for our `.togglable` span tags. Now the CSS:

```
.togglable+ul {
    display:none;
}
.togglable.toggled+ul {
    display:block;
}
/* the '+' just selects the <ul> sibling right
   after the <span class="togglable"> */
```

That's it. Go crazy with CSS, but these are the basics to CSS hover/togglable menus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @philtune I'm really trying to work with what i have and i'm just going to look into editing the jquery.